# How to access object's property returned from Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, console.log

I'm a React beginner and having this little problem that I can't get my head around.

I successfully retrive data from Firestore and update the state `items`. When I logged `item[1]` it returned the object with expected properties `id`, `name`, `description` but when trying `item[1].id` it gave me **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined** error

Could you please give me a hint on what could be wrong here?

This is what my code looks like

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import db from '../../../firestore';

const Carousel = () => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('destinations')
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const data = [];
                querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    data.push(doc.data())
                })
                setItems(data);
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(items[1])} {/* This works  */}
            {console.log(items[1].id)} {/* This gave error */}
        </div>
    )
};

export default Carousel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since emtpy array is a truthy value you need to do this in your return

```
return (
    <div>
        {items[1] &&
            <div>{items[1].id}</div> 
        }
    </div>
)
```

You need to check for `items[1]`, when it is rendering, you can only access when `items` has the data.
When it is empty, accessing the `id` will give you the error you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Utsav!
Am I right to assume when on the first render `items` was still empty and therefore the component has no choice but running into that undefined error and stuck there before `items` state is set on the second render?

Comment: Yes that is correct.
To make it even simpler, on first render `items` would be whatever you gave in `useState` while inititalizing.  
So `items` is `[]`, therefore `items[1]` is undefined. 
Till now no error, but the moment you do `items[1].id`, this becomes `undefined.id` and then you will face an error.